# Access to a drive through a VPN

Tags: windows, vpn, windows-server-2012-r2

I bought a hosted VPS (with Windows Server 2012) on which i would like to do two things:
- Run a client/server application
- Map as a letter a drive

The idea is to connect through a VPN to secure the data transfer, and to let me access remotely to my files.

Do I need a DC ? What about the certificate ? 
What are the essential steps you could recommend me to do in order to set up ?

Thanks in advance
Thomas

Comment: Are you asking how to set up the VPN or how to map the drive after the VPN is up and running? If the former, your question is too broad. If the latter, then you mainly just need name resolution of some kind and there has to be at least one share configured on the server. Then it's just like mapping a drive to a local server.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy. First connect VPN and then connect a share with the Explorer.exe.
In a VPN everything works like in a LAN.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many users are connecting to the server, I would not setup a DC unless you need one for other reasons.

Create any needed user accounts for access to the files.

Create the file share(s) and assign permissions as needed.

Setup the VPN access for the user(s).

Setup the client VPN side.

Map the network drive using the server's local IP Address. If you want to use hostname, you will either need some sort of DNS server (and settings on the client to use the DNS server) or HOSTS file redirection.

Now to look at your files, as FrankStein said, just connect to the VPN and access files through Windows Explorer. The traffic is encrypted in transit through the VPN tunnel but will be accessible to any application on your computer as if it was on the LAN.